# Cannot install PiVPN

Tags: curl

For some reason I fail to install PiVPN on my raspberry Pi

I run `curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash`

but the output I get is

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   178  100   178    0     0    203      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   204
100 59085  100 59085    0     0  49827      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  230k
:::
::: sudo will be used for the install.
main: Zeile 100: VER_MAP: Falscher Feldbezeichner.
```

Sorry, I don't know what the english version of the last line is. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Update:
Output of `cat /etc/os-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: `main: Zeile 100: VER_MAP: Falscher Feldbezeichner.` (deutsh) mean `
`main: Line 100: VER_MAP: Incorrect field identifier.` (english) . Have you try to run your command with `sudo` ?

Comment: Yes I have, same result

Comment: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pivpn/pivpn/master/auto_install/install.sh`, `chmod +x install.sh`, `sudo bash install.sh` ?

Comment: your error is at line 100 of this script : `OSCN=${VER_MAP["${VER}"]}`

Comment: try this in your terminal: `source /etc/os-release` and then `echo $VERSION_ID` ... what is your output ? Must be `10 for buster" "9 for stretch" "8 for jessie" "18.04 for bionic" "16.04 for xenial" or "14.04 trusty"`

Comment: I don't get an output, but I'm running on `stretch`. The `wget` solution doesn't work, same result.

Comment: If you use stretch then must must have an output of `9`, if empty or not work, update your `stretch` to `buster` because your OS is out of date.

Comment: Next time please prepend commands with `LANG=C` before posting, for example `LANG=C bash --version`. This will give its output in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main: Zeile 100: VER_MAP: Falscher Feldbezeichner.` (deutsh) mean `main: Line 100: VER_MAP: Incorrect field identifier.` (english)

Error is at line `100` of the [install.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pivpn/pivpn/master/auto_install/install.sh)

```
 96. source /etc/os-release
 97. PLAT=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$NAME")
 98. VER="$VERSION_ID"
 99. declare -A VER_MAP=(["10"]="buster" ["9"]="stretch" ["8"]="jessie" ["18.04"]="bionic" ["16.04"]="xenial" ["14.04"]="trusty")
100. OSCN=${VER_MAP["${VER}"]}
```

Try this in your terminal:

`source /etc/os-release`

then

`echo $VERSION_ID` and check your output.

Must be :

- `10` for buster
- `9` for stretch
- `8` for jessie
- `18.04` for bionic
- `16.04` for xenial
- `14.04` trusty

You can check for error with this new lines in the script :

```
source /etc/os-release
PLAT=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$NAME")
VER="$VERSION_ID"
declare -A VER_MAP=(["10"]="buster" ["9"]="stretch" ["8"]="jessie" ["18.04"]="bionic" ["16.04"]="xenial" ["14.04"]="trusty")
if [ -z "$VER" ]||[[ ! ${!VER_MAP[@]} =~ $VER ]];then
    echo "This script is not supported on your release version: ${VER} , try for supported OS !"
    OSCN=
    #exit 0
else:
    OSCN=${VER_MAP["${VER}"]}
fi;
```

The script next code is :

```
case ${PLAT} in
        Ubuntu|Raspbian|Debian|Devuan)
        case ${OSCN} in
            trusty|xenial|jessie|stretch|buster|bionic)
            ;;
            *)
            maybeOS_Support
```

That mean if you check for error and set the variable `OSCN` only if any errors exists. In your case the script will be able to continue and arrive at the following function : `maybeOS_Support` ... But in your case you specified to use `Raspbian Stretch` then update your out-of-date Raspbian and try again to install because `$VERSION_ID` must return `9 for Stretch`

Comment: Little update, I updated my os to `buster`, the curl works now altough the `$VERSION_ID` still returns null, therefore the installer doesn't recognize the os.

Comment: @po.pe , can you update your question with your `cat /etc/os-release` output pls ?

Comment: @po.pe, sorry but the supported versions array not contain `Bullseye` release : `VER_MAP=(["10"]="buster" ["9"]="stretch" ["8"]="jessie" ["18.04"]="bionic" ["16.04"]="xenial" ["14.04"]="trusty")` . You can try to put ["11"]="bullseye" in the array and add in the case `bullseye` but it is likely that further changes will be necessary. Maybe wait for the author of the project to update it.

Comment: @po.pe, but your `os-release` file seems to be 'broken' ... try to add manually : `VERSION_ID="11"` for `Bullseye` (but see my previous comment.)

Comment: Okay, no idea why I didn't end up with `buster`...